# sed adding replacement text twice

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I've never seen sed behave like this but I'm trying to replace all instances of "nameserver" within /etc/resolv.conf with my own 3 entries, including the "nameserver". Every combo I've tried adds my 3 entries twice, so I have 6 entries.

`sed -i 's/.*nameserver.*/nameserver 10.1.1.1\nnameserver 10.1.1.2\nnameserver 10.1.1.3/g' /etc/resolv.conf`

which outputs

```
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 10.1.1.2
nameserver 10.1.1.3
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 10.1.1.2
nameserver 10.1.1.3
```

So, the correct order and entries but adding it twice. I've also tried narrowing it down to nameserver and ip but still get the same output printed twice.

`sed -i "s/^nameserver [0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/nameserver 10.1.1.1\nnameserver 10.1.1.2\nnameserver 10.1.1.3/g"`

I'm really confused here and can't seem to get past this. Any help appreciated.

ETA:
current resolv.conf

```
search domain1.net. domain2.net. domaine.com.
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
```

desired output

```
search domain1.net. domain2.net. domaine.com.
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 10.1.1.2
nameserver 10.1.1.3
```

Comment: Please add your resolv.conf and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I can't reproduce the problem with my resolv.conf, so you need to make a [mre], like Cyrus mentioned.

Comment: You have two occurrences of `nameserver` in the original, so sed replaces each of them. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really. This script is going to be run on a few thousand hosts and they vary with 1 entry in resolv.conf to 3...I just want to replace every nameserver line with the new entries...No matter what I try I get 6 entries from my 3 that I want...So they're being doubled and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two occurrences of "nameserver" in the original, so `sed` replaces each of them.

You can do [multiline replacements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/117037) with `sed`, but it's simpler to delete the lines you don't want, then append the ones you do. Though I'm not familiar with `/etc/resolv.conf` so I don't know if order matters.

```
sed '/nameserver.*/d' /etc/resolv.conf
cat <<'EOF'
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 10.1.1.2
nameserver 10.1.1.3
EOF
```

If the output looks good from this, run the below to actually make the changes:

```
sudo sed -i '/nameserver.*/d' /etc/resolv.conf
sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf >/dev/null <<'EOF'
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 10.1.1.2
nameserver 10.1.1.3
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! Was able to get it working...still aggravated that I can't figure out why I'm getting multiple entries, even across different OS's (rhel6 and 7) but I've beat my head against it long enough...thanks again!

Comment: @cubezombie Welcome! I'm not sure why you're confused about the repeats though. Like I mentioned, `sed` replaces **each** of the matched lines.

Comment: Right, but in my original 2 examples I had 3 nameservers defined...it would create duplicate entries for each one leaving me with 6 nameserver entries in the order I had them but just doubled. You're method worked perfectly but it's the double entries in my earlier method I'm still confused about.